# Lubuntu starts then transitions to ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I am trying to revamp an old PC. I installed the latest Ubuntu (14.04) but it's way too slow to use I assume due to my 11 year old video card. Based on advice in forums, I then proceeded to install Lubuntu. When logging in to lubuntu, it seems to want to start (The blue background is on the screen), however within a minute or so it transitions to regular Ubuntu. Any ideas as to what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Strange... Just a suggestion-Make sure lubuntu is fully installed.

Comment: I would not assume the problem is necessarily your video card.  You'd be amazed what technologically backward graphics cards can still deliver in a relatively modern pc.  I would be much more suspicious of the amount of RAM in your system.  In my experience, 1.25gb ram is the minimum amount required for Ubuntu 12.04 to work marginally well.  Even 1g is not quite enough to not end in frustration.  So, how much do you have?

Comment: Did you install **lubuntu** or **lxde** in a regular ubuntu installation? If you install lubuntu I doubt it even has a unity fall-back

Answer (score 1):

Since what you have now isn't what you want.  Download and do a fresh install of Lubuntu 14.04.  I have it on an old (10 years) Dell Inspiron 1000 and it runs great.